# An identity for the binomial of the totient function

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Today, to the stack community, I'm posting a question which I am not sure whether it holds good for huge numbers or not, and neither have proof for the same.

Let $\phi(n)$ be the Euler's totient function, where $n\in N$. Now if we denote $P$ as the set of prime numbers $p\in P,(p>2)$ then following congruence according to me must hold true always.

$${1+2\phi(p^2) \choose \phi(p^2)} \equiv \phi(p^2) \pmod{p^2}$$

I don't have any idea for the proof of the same. Although, I've tried a lot to prove it. I will discuss some of my failed attempts here.

**Attempt: 1**

I used simple simplification for the binomial.
$${n+1 \choose r} = \frac{n+1}{n+1-r}{n \choose r}$$
We have,
$${1+2\phi(p^2) \choose \phi(p^2)} = \frac{1+2\phi(p^2)}{1+\phi(p^2)}{2\phi(p^2) \choose \phi(p^2)}$$
Now, ${ap \choose bp} \equiv {a \choose b} \pmod{p^2}$.
But the fraction in front of the combination cannot be simplified further.

**Attempt: 2**
$${1+2\phi(p^2) \choose \phi(p^2)} = {-1+2(\phi(p^2)+1) \choose -1+(1+\phi(p^2))}$$
Let, $1+\phi(p^2) = t$, then,
$$2{-1 + 2t \choose t-1} = {2t \choose t}$$
And lastly using VanderMonde's identity for the binomial,
$${2t \choose t} = \sum_{i = 0}^t{t \choose i}^2$$.

But this approach also leads to a dead end with a summation which is not easy to be simplified further.

I will be thankful to the stack community if someone takes their valuable time and help me to figure out first whether this identity always holds, and if it holds, then how one can prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first method works, but you made a slight mistake and didn’t go far enough. Use the fact that $\phi(p^2)=p(p-1)=p^2-p\equiv-p$ to get
$$\begin{aligned} \binom{1+2p(p-1)}{p(p-1)} &= \frac{1+2p(p-1)}{1+p(p-1)}\cdot\binom{2p(p-1)}{p(p-1)} \\ &\equiv \frac{1+2p(p-1)}{1+p(p-1)}\cdot\binom{2p-2}{p-1} && \text{applying wolstenholme’s theorem} \\ &\equiv \frac{1+2p(p-1)}{1+p(p-1)}\cdot\frac{p}{2p-1}\cdot\binom{2p-1}{p-1} \\ &\equiv \frac{1+2p(p-1)}{1+p(p-1)}\cdot\frac{p}{2p-1} && \text{wolstenholme again} \\ &\equiv (1-2p)(1+p)p(2p-1)^{-1} && \text{turning fractions into multiplicative inverses and reducing mod }p^2 \\ &\equiv -p(2p-1)(2p-1)^{-1} \\ &\equiv -p \\ &\equiv \phi(p^2)\end{aligned}$$

Edit: to clarify the step where I reduce the fractions mod $p^2$: this is justified because both denominators are relatively prime to $p^2$, and because $(1+p(p-1))^{-1}\equiv(1-p)^{-1}\equiv1+p$ (because $(1-p)(1+p)=1-p^2$)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done till last fifth step but then I was not able to reduce fraction and was stuck there. But I’m not getting how congruence to -p turns out to be equivalent to congruence to $\phi(p^2)$. I would be thankful if you clarify it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your answer. The fraction reduction step dont came to my mind for proving it. Your answer is of real worth to me.

Comment: @Aziz $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$, so in this case $\phi(p^2)=p^2-p$ which is congruent to $-p$ modulo $p^2$.

Comment: Got that. Thank you iosce